# Customs charge for bringing a 3D printer into India?

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india, electronic-items

I am travelling from US to India via Qatar, I am carrying a Prusa 8" i3v kit.

The dimensions of the box are 18×18×6, and it weighs around 9kg.
If I check the 3D printer box with my luggage, will there be any issues with the customs department in India? Do I need to pay customs charge for it?

If I ship it with FedEx-like services, do I still need to pay customs and import charges for a 3D printer?

Comment: I don't know about india, but here fedex usually pays the customs for you after which I will get a bill from fedex for these costs.

Comment: well i can do it, if i have a team like phineas and ferb :) , i am looking for some good suggestions guys.

Comment: Like @andra, I don't have experience with India specifically but usually customs duties depend on the value of the goods, not size, and are due no matter how you import them (I know people who have been fined for books sent by post).

Comment: Actually, there is a difference: there’s usually a small allowance for goods you bring in yourself, while there isn’t one (or it’s very very low) for goods imported by post.

Answer (score 1):

It'll likely depend on the value of the 3D Printer.  Generally customs is concerned with you bringing more than one item in - i.e. you're importing stuff for sale, and then they'll want to charge you import taxes.

However, if it's just one and it's only for personal use, this *generally* isn't a problem, depending on the value of the item.

Once it gets over a certain value, then it may come into question.

Your best option is to look at the [Indian Customs Guide for Travellers](http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf), as it breaks down all the rules based on items, your status (resident/traveller/business), and what you're allowed to bring in, its value, and how many of particular other items (some are restricted - eg cigarettes).

If in doubt, you can always contact Indian Customs directly, with details contained within that document.